# using react native Airbnb markers in a modal view

Tags: arrays, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app that will utilize react native map view. I want it when a user clicks on the map marker that it will populate the information in a modal view. How do I go about pulling this information from firebase?

I tried doing an object.keys but it doesn't work.

```
<Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
             animationType={'fade'}
             animationOut={'slideOutDown'}
             animationOutTiming={200}
             backdropColor={'black'}
             backdropOpacity={0.70}
             backdropTransitionInTiming={200} 
             hideOnBack={false}  
             toValue={0}
             onRequestClose={() => {alert('close me')}}
             style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginLeft: 20, marginBottom: 100}}>
        <View style={{width: 280, height: 200, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: 'white',}}>
        <View style={{width: 220, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'white', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', }}>
          <View style={{width: 220, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 15, alignSelf: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between',}}>
            <View style={{width: 100, height: 100,}}>
             {Object.keys(this.state.restuarants).map(function (key) {
            var val = this.state.newEatingSpot[key];
              return 
            <Image source={{uri: val.restuarantImage}}
                   style={{width: 100, height: 100,}}/>
                     },this)
    }
            </View>
```